# I want to install Ubuntu leaving Windows 8 and recovery partitions untouched

Tags: dual-boot, partitioning, system-installation, lenovo

I tried installing ubuntu using a usb in my pre-installed windows 8 machine which is lenovo z500.

If I have to install ubuntu, do I have to make a partition in my C-drive?

Is there another method in which I don't have to erase my c-drive and install ubuntu?.

I dont want to disturb C drive as the one key recovery software of lenovo doesnt work if c drive is partitioned.

**I AM A BEGINNER AND DONT KNOW MUCH OF THE TECHNICAL STUFF IN LINUX. So a detailed description is appreciated..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to install Ubuntu you need at least an empty partition.
Therefore you can install Ubuntu having Linux's c: (which is called root denoted by `/`) inside that empty partition.

To check whether you have empty partitions from Windows 8, use the [disk management utility](http://pcsupport.about.com/od/windows-8/a/disk-management-windows-8.htm)

If you don't have one, you can resize an existing partition and make a new partition for Ubuntu from the same utility.

[image]

You are advised to backup your data before manipulating partitions.

---

Alternatively you can install Ubuntu in your usb pen drive.
Simply choose the disk as your pen drive at Ubuntu installation. (It should be shown as either `sdb` or `sdc` in the Ubuntu installer)
You might need to write Ubuntu to a CD as well.

Comment: I have done the 2nd option..it worked. thanx!

Comment: Glad to help...!

Answer (score 1):

First of all if you only have once drive then you will have to partition it.

The other option is using "wubi", this will install Ubuntu like a program that can be uninstalled in the "programs" in control panel.
https://wiki.ubuntu.com/WubiGuide

The other option is to create a bootable Ubuntu USB drive, in this no changes are made to the system and all settings are saved to the USB drive.

Comment: AFAIK Wubi doesn't work with Windows 8

Comment: WUBI doesn't work with *UEFI,* which is a type of firmware that's replacing the old BIOS. Computers that ship with Windows 8 almost invariably use UEFI. AFAIK WUBI remains compatible with Windows 8 installed *in BIOS mode,* but since that happens mostly with upgraded computers, it's not really an issue for user287924, who's specified that the computer has a pre-installed Windows 8.

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can install ubuntu on a pen drive. For this boot from a CD/DVD during installation select *custom install* then select the partition on usb drive.
Remember as you install on low speed device you will get lower performance.